# Adobe FMS 4.5 only showing 1 active connection

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, adobe, flash-media-server

I am running a live stream using Adobe Flash Media Server 4.5, running on a Amazon Web Services EC2 server.

I know that there are at least 5 active connections, but when I log into the FMS server admin console, it only tells me that there is one.

What options do I have configured wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using HDS streaming rather than RTMP. The single connection is the encoder. The apache webserver is handling the incoming connections.

Comment: I discovered what you said thorough other sources as well. The apache webserver doesn't give me nearly the kind of stats I wanted, that FMS provides - looks like I'll have to just go with RTMP streaming

Comment: I'm using Google Analytics embeded in the Player iframe to monitor current users and using event triggers to do some more logging. Not a great solution but better than nothing.